# Swift Codable: Decode different array of items with same root objects

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable, decodable

I'm currently trying to decode JSON which looks like this:

```json
{
  "result": {
    "success": true,
    "items": [
      {
        "timeEntryID": "1",
        "start": "1519558200",
        "end": "1519563600",
        "customerName": "Test-Customer",
        "projectName": "Test-Project",
        "description": "Entry 1",
      },
      {
        "timeEntryID": "2",
        "start": "1519558200",
        "end": "1519563600",
        "customerName": "Test-Customer",
        "projectName": "Test-Project",
        "description": "Entry 2",
      }
    ],
    "total": "2"
  },
  "id": "1"
}
```

The decoding process for this specific type of JSON is pretty simple. I just need something like this:

```swift
struct ResponseKeys: Decodable {
    let result: ResultKeys

    struct ResultKeys: Decodable {
        let success: Bool
        let items: [Item]
    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that every response of the server has the same structure as the above JSON but with different item types. So sometimes it is `let items: [Item]` but it could also be `let items: [User]` if I make a call to the User endpoint.

Because it would be an unnecessary duplication of code if I would write the above swift code for every endpoint with just the modification of the items array, I created a custom decoder:

```swift
enum KimaiAPIResponseKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case result

    enum KimaiResultKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success
        case items
    }
}

struct Activity: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let description: String?
    let customerName: String
    let projectName: String
    let startDateTime: Date
    let endDateTime: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "timeEntryID"
        case description
        case customerName
        case projectName
        case startDateTime = "start"
        case endDateTime = "end"
    }
}

extension Activity {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let resultContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: KimaiAPIResponseKeys.self)
        let itemsContainer = try resultContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: KimaiAPIResponseKeys.KimaiResultKeys.self, forKey: .result)
        let activityContainer = try itemsContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Activity.CodingKeys.self, forKey: .items)

        id = Int(try activityContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .id))!
        description = try activityContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)
        customerName = try activityContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .customerName)
        projectName = try activityContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .projectName)
        startDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(try activityContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .startDateTime))!)
        endDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(try activityContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .endDateTime))!)
    }

}
```

The decoder works perfectly if `"items"` does only contain a single object and not an array:

```json
{
  "result": {
    "success": true,
    "items":
      {
        "timeEntryID": "2",
        "start": "1519558200",
        "end": "1519563600",
        "customerName": "Test-Customer",
        "projectName": "Test-Project",
        "description": "Entry 2",
      },
    "total": "2"
  },
  "id": "1"
}
```

If `items` is an array I get the following error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [__lldb_expr_151.KimaiAPIResponseKeys.result], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

**I just cannot figure out how to modify my decoder to work with an array of items.** I created a Playground file with the working and not working version of the JSON. Please take a look and try it out: [Decodable.playground](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sxY02bBmxB34DBynp9vkAbcA6-WVnSdi)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to decode the dictionary/dictionaries for `items` separately

```
struct Item : Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "timeEntryID"
        case description, customerName, projectName
        case startDateTime = "start"
        case endDateTime = "end"
    }

    let id: Int
    let startDateTime: Date
    let endDateTime: Date
    let customerName: String
    let projectName: String
    let description: String?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id))!
        description = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)
        customerName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .customerName)
        projectName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .projectName)
        startDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .startDateTime))!)
        endDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .endDateTime))!)
    }
}
```

And in `Activity` use a conditional initializer, it provides it's own `do catch` block. First it tries to decode a single item and assigns the single item as array to the property. If it fails it decodes an array.

```
enum KimaiAPIResponseKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case result, id

    enum KimaiResultKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success
        case items
    }
}

struct Activity: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let items: [Item]
}

extension Activity {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let rootContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: KimaiAPIResponseKeys.self)
        id = try rootContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        let resultContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: KimaiAPIResponseKeys.KimaiResultKeys.self, forKey: .result)
        do {
            let item = try resultContainer.decode(Item.self, forKey: .items)
            items = [item]
        } catch {
            items = try resultContainer.decode([Item].self, forKey: .items)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I think you are right that I need to write a custom decoder for the items separately. If I would implement your answer than I could decode JSON which has a single Item or an array of Items but I always have an array which can contain different types. eg User/Activity. "Item" was just a generic term for these types. How could I accomplish this behavior since I need to specify the type in "let items: [here]"

Comment: Just make `Activity` generic: `struct Activity<Item: Decodable>`, and it will work the same.

Comment: @RobNapier That was the decisive point! So simple. Thank you and vadian. I really appreciate your helpful answers!

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use **Generics**, It's a neat way to deal with this situation.

```
  struct MainClass<T: Codable>: Codable  {
     let result: Result<T>
     let id: String
  }

  struct Result <T: Codable>: Codable {
     let success: Bool
     let items: [T]
     let total: String
  }
```

and here you will get the items

```
   let data = Data()
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   let modelObjet = try! decoder.decode(MainClass<User>.self, from: data)
   let users = modelObjet.result.items
```

In my opinion, **Generics** is the best way to handle the duplication of code like this situations.

Comment: This is exactly how I did it. Generics rock!